# ESRI JavaScript API FeatureLayer Click Event

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo, events

I am using FeatureLayers in the API to load in a layer.  I have an info template set for the layer for identifying individual features.

I am trying to disconnect the click event from the layer while I am drawing a polygon for another tool.  However, I haven't found a good way to disconnect that handler since it isn't one I assign.

I have tried `layer.disableMapEvents()` which didn't work.  I don't have an info template set for the map itself either, so I don't think that one is firing.

I have searched through some other posts here, and so far the only solution I have found is to attach another handler to the map click event and call `map.infoWindow.hide()` while I am doing the drawing.  This still goes through the identify process but keeps the window away.

I also tried calling the `map.graphics.disableMouseEvents()`, but that doesn't work either.

I am looking for a way to either handle the map click event myself and disconnect ESRI's standard way for the FeatureLayer.  I just want to be able to shut off identifying of features temporarily.

A way to disconnect the event and hook it up again would be great.  That would help if I want to attach it to another mouse event, too.

Comment: Posted on https://geonet.esri.com/message/433454#433454 too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'm not sure why .disableMouseEvents() stopped working after 3.9, but you can use map.setInfoWindowOnClick() instead.

[here's](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59331579/js/setInfoWindowOnClick.html) a working sample.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  I am disappointed I missed it in their documentation.

Comment: IMO easy to miss cause its a method of the map and not the FeatureLayer itself.  glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

This sample may help you. I don't think you should need disableMouseEvents or disableMapEvents. I was able to use this to keep map click events separate from selecting features and managed to build a few other things on as well.

The initSelectToolbar function runs once after clicking the button and then finishes after selecting features (but I think drawing a polygon could be done here too). The button does need to be pressed again for each new polygon.

[Feature Layer with Selection](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/fl_selectfeatures.html) (Sample)

Answer (score 0):

using dojo/on.pausable is a cool way to handle stopping and starting the listening of events.

```
this.identifying = on.pausable(this.map, 'click', (evt) => this.onMapClick(evt));
```

and then when you want to draw or something

```
if (!active) {
  return this.identifying.pause();
}

this.identifying.resume();
```